# I cant get my constructors from my subclasses to read the Strings I have put in them

Tags: java

I am trying to get my constructors from my subclasses to read the `Strings` which I have put in them. I keep getting `null` for the output, when it should be `ChildrensBook`, I am confused on what to do. Any help is appreciated thank you.

This is my assignment:

> Design and implement a set of classes that define types of reading material: books, novels, magazines, technical journals, textbooks, and so on. Include data values that describe material, such as the number of pages and the names of the authors. Include methods that are named for each class and that print an appropriate message. Create a main driver class to instaniate several of the classes.

My Java code:

Driver:

```
public class Reading{

public static void main(String[]args)  
{  
   Book book       = new Book(null, 0, 0, 0);  
   Magazine mag    = new Magazine(null, 0, 0);  
   Journal journal = new Journal(null, 0, 0, 0);  
   Textbook txt    = new Textbook(null, 0, 0, 0);  
   Manual manual   = new Manual(null, 0, 0, 0);

   book.print();  
   mag.print();  
   journal.print();  
   txt.print();  
   manual.print();
}
```

SuperClass:

```
public class ReadingMaterial {

  String type;

  int pages, characters, numPictures;

  public ReadingMaterial(String type, int pages, int characters, int numPictures)  
  {  
      this.type        = type;  
      this.pages       = pages;  
      this.characters  = characters; 
      this.numPictures = numPictures;
  }  

  public void print()
  {     
      System.out.println("Reading Material Data: "); 
      System.out.println("");
      System.out.println("Type of reading material: " +type);  
      System.out.println("Number of pages: " +pages);  
      System.out.println("Number of primary characters: " +characters);  
      System.out.println("Number of pictures: " +numPictures);
      System.out.println("");
  }  
}
```

And one of the subclasses:

```
public class Book extends ReadingMaterial 
{  
   public Book(String type, int pages, int characters, int numPictures)  
   {  
     super("ChildrensBook", 22, 5, 20);  
   }    
}
```

Comment: Could you post the output?

Comment: _"keep getting null for the output, when it should be ChildrensBook"_ Because you're passing a null String as first argument of your Book constructor. By the way your super call should be : `super(ChildrensBook,pages,characters,numPictures);`. And try to respect naming conventions (i.e String childrensBook).

Comment: Reading Material Data: 

Type of reading material: null
Number of pages: 22
Number of primary characters: 5
Number of pictures: 20

Comment: If i try to remove the null from the main it just redlines it and it wont let me put anything else to run

Comment: @TheNamesZero You need to pass the correct number of arguments to your constructor. Why do you want to pass null as type ? Try `Book book = new Book("This is a type", 0, 0, 0);`

Comment: Oops wasnt putting quotations around the string. I was putting it in like this Book book = new Book(ChildrensBook,0,0,0);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you should do. You should pass the `String` that you expect the type to have.

```
Book book = new Book("ChildrensBook", 0,0,0);
```

you are getting `null` because you are passing it `null`.

EDIT:

Also please use proper coding standards while naming the variables. A variable should start with a small letter and then should be camel cased.

```
 public Book(String nameOfTheBook, int pages, int characters, int numPictures){  
     super(nameOfTheBook,22,5,20);  
 }
```

Comment: ok wow.  I feel silly its because i wasnt putting quotations around the childrensbook when i put it.

Comment: A string in java should be contained within `""` double quotes.

Comment: this is what i get for working on it early in the morning lol

Comment: No problem. I hope you got the answer.

Comment: It works now, i have another question though. In the subclass why does it allow me to pick which ints I want in the constructor but not in the main.

Comment: See the edited answer. Also I don't get your last comment. I would recommend you to post it as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you're passing `null` to your child classes:

```
    Book book = new Book(null, 0, 0, 0);  
    Magazine mag = new Magazine(null, 0, 0);  
    Journal journal= new Journal(null, 0, 0, 0);  
    Textbook txt = new Textbook(null, 0, 0, 0);  
    Manual manual= new Manual(null, 0, 0, 0);
```